# Getting this exception : Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm using the same key and iv for both encrypt and decrypt cipher. This is an intermittent issue. What am I doing wrong?

I'm keeping the key and iv in DB and it is loaded at the time of service startup. encrytCipher and DecryptCipher are initialized with these values.

Data loading and initialization happen once and later the ciphers are reused

```
public class TestEncrypter {

    EncrypterUtil util;

    
    private Cipher encryptCipher = null;
    private Cipher decryptCipher = null;
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) throws Exception {
        if (strToEncrypt == null || strToEncrypt.isEmpty()) {
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
        try {
            initCiphers();
            String encrypterStr = Base64.getEncoder()
                    .encodeToString(encryptCipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharset.UTF_8)));
       
            return encrypterStr;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while encryption  : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) throws Exception {
        if (strToDecrypt == null || strToDecrypt.isEmpty()) {
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
        try {
            initCiphers();
            String decryptedStr = new String(decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
       
            return decryptedStr;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while decryption  : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the common encrypter.
     * 
     * @param myKey
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public void initCiphers() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        if (encryptCipher == null || decryptCipher == null) {

            String secret = util.get("KEY"); // reading key from DB
            byte[] key = secret.getBytes(StandardCharset.UTF_8);
            key = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            byte[] i = Arrays.copyOf(util.get("IV").getBytes(), 16); // reading iv from DB
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(i);

            encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

            decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The intermittent issue is probably due to `Encrypter` is not thread safe.

Comment: Intermittent as in few setups has issue and few dosen't.

Comment: There is no reason for the `Cipher` objects to be class members. Make them method-local and your thread-safety problem will disappear.